# Prolog: Compare 2 Lists and find out if at least one member of the first list exists in the other one

Tags: prolog

In the quest of learning more about prolog (and in the interest of solving my assignment), I have come across a situation where I need to compare 2 lists and find out if **AT LEAST ONE** element match ...
Here is an example what I want to do:

```
?-match([a,b,c],[x,y,z]).
no.

?-match([a,b,c],[x,y,b]).
yes.
```

My solution up to now:

```
compare_list([],[]).
compare_list([],_).
compare_list([L1Head|L1Tail],List2):-
    member(L1Head,List2),
    compare_list(L1Tail,List2).
```

but this solution gives a `true` when all the members of List1 are present in List2!

Please people, don't think that I am cheating on an assignment, the problem is much much more complex, I am just stuck at this point and need help to get out of this sticky corner... otherwise I have done the entire assignment myself!

Comment: Does your school allow you to ask for help on your assignments? most schools don't and consider it an academic offense.

Comment: @ChristianF this is not my main assignment... it is much more complex, I am just stuck on this small problem...

Comment: This is a fairly basic list processing problem. I'd suggest looking up some examples of list processing (such as here: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) and have a look at the `member/2` predicate in the prolog documentation.

Comment: @mbratch I have already looked into this actually, I have also made a solution based on member/2 but it only succeeds ALL items of first list are also present in second list... I could show you my solution if you like?

Comment: If you would like help on SO, it's actually required in the guidelines that you show your attempts. So, yes, edit your problem and add your attempted code.

Comment: @mbratch I have added my idea... but it is not working at the moment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll comment on the attempt you've made, which is close, but not quite there:

```
compare_list([],[]).
compare_list([],_).
```

The first clause for `compare_list/2` says that the empty list has at least one element in the empty list. The second says the empty list has at least one element in any other list. So the first clause is redundant (it's already covered by the second). Whether you want this to be true (that an empty list has an element in any other list) is up to you. Since an empty list has no members, one might consider this a failure case (and, thus, not be declared as true) but you can call it true by definition if you wish. However, it will cause some issues in the recursive case once you have your predicate correctly defined since reducing down to `[]` will become true and ultimately it might find any list has elements in any list (oops!). I'd leave these two clauses out and consider this case a fail.

```
compare_list([L1Head|L1Tail], List2):-
    member(L1Head, List2),
    compare_list(L1Tail, List2).
```

This says that the first list has an element in the second list if: (1) the head of the list is a member of the second list, AND (2) the tail of the first list has an element in the second list. Does this sound logically correct? If you think this through, given there are no additional `compare_list/2` clauses, this is true only if EVERY element of the first list is a member of the second list, as you have observed.

Finally, you're missing the case where the first list has a head that is not a member of the second list. This shouldn't necessarily be a failure since the tail of the first list may have a member in the second list, even if the first element (head) is not a member.

Comment: Ok, but how do I iterate through all the elements of the first list to find out if there is a match in the second list?

Comment: Same way you did it in your attempt. You do a recursive call on the tail. Eventually, it will lead to `[]` and that case should be considered a failure (as indicated in my answer)

Comment: but I have done that and it doesn't work as I would like it to, it only gives me true if all the members are matching. How do I stop as soon as I get the first match and return a true?

Comment: Please read my answer above carefully. The problem is that your recursive call is in the same clause as the case that should just succeed without it (as I described in the answer). You only need a recursive call in this case if the head of the first list is NOT a member of the second list, which is a case you didn't cover.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to thank you here, but still, Thank you very much! And one last thing, could you please mark my question up, since when I posted the question, some poor choice of words and some incomplete information led to someone thinking I was trying to cheat on my assignment, but then I updated and explained the situation.

Answer (score 5):

your problem can be solved using the simpler builtins

```
match(L1,L2) :- member(E,L1),member(E,L2). % full join
```

add the nasty cut if you are really interested only in 'at least one' solution

```
match(L1,L2) :- member(E,L1),memberchk(E,L2),!. % really, just the first!
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your example predicate *match/2*. The solution is as simple as traverse recursively the List1 (on the left) and check if the Head belongs to the List2 via the *memberchk/2* predicate. The reason to use *memberchk/2* is that it succeeds only once (i.e., not re-executable on backtracking) and this is what your "**AT LEAST ONE**" condition states. If the List1 is empty, the predicate fails.

**Code:**

```
match([Head|Tail], List2):-
        memberchk(Head,List2).
match([_|Tail],List2):-
        match(Tail,List2).
```

**Examples:**

```
| ?-  match([a,b,c],[x,y,z]).
no

| ?-  match([a,b,c],[x,y,b]).
yes

| ?-  match([a,b,c],[]).     
no

| ?-  match([],[x,y,b]).
no
```

Comment: You don't need an explicit `match([], _):- fail.` Leaving that clause off will do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use nth0 predicate.

```
match(L1, L2) :-
    nth0(_, L1, SharedItem),
    nth0(_, L2, SharedItem).
```

The first nth0 says "is there a L1 list item with index '_' (ie don't care whether it is in first, second etc. position in the list), whose name is variable SharedItem.

The second nth0 does the same for L2.

But the nice trick is in the unification.. by using the same variable name SharedItem on both nth's, prolog will continue iterating through the lists until the same item is in both.

As always the 'trace.' predicate is your best friend.. run it before calling the above to see what prolog is doing in the background:

```
[trace]  ?- match([a,b,c],[x,y,b]).
   Call: (6) match([a, b, c], [x, y, b]) ? creep
   Call: (7) lists:nth0(_G1965, [a, b, c], _G1967) ? creep
   Exit: (7) lists:nth0(0, [a, b, c], a) ? creep
   Call: (7) lists:nth0(_G1968, [x, y, b], a) ? creep
   Fail: (7) lists:nth0(_G1968, [x, y, b], a) ? creep
   Redo: (7) lists:nth0(_G1968, [a, b, c], _G1970) ? creep
   Exit: (7) lists:nth0(1, [a, b, c], b) ? creep
   Call: (7) lists:nth0(_G1968, [x, y, b], b) ? creep
   Exit: (7) lists:nth0(2, [x, y, b], b) ? creep
   Exit: (6) match([a, b, c], [x, y, b]) ? creep
true .
```

So the 'outer' loop is L1.. it first tries index 0 of L1(a), then when it fails to find it in L2, it does a Redo (of the first nth0), but this time with index 1(b), and finds it, then returns true.