# Prolog subgroup of list of size n

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a rule to determine if a list is a sublist of size n of another list.

```
isSubgroup/3
isSubgroup(+Subgroup, +Group, +N)
```

For example, `isSubgroup([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)` would return `True`

However, `isSubgroup([4, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)` would return `False` (because of the different order)

I thought of checking for each member of the subgroup whether or not it's a member of the large group, but that would ignore the order.

Is the idea feasible?

Comment: Hint: try to come up with an *inductive* definition.

Comment: Another hint: Do it on paper first and then write down the instructions as if you were giving it to someone else to do. Then translate that into Prolog. Odds are you can write down the steps, but then will have trouble translating that to Prolog. That is probably the question you then want to post as an update to this question.

Comment: @CapelliC: That likely is *Turing*, and *Turing* is not the only one. In fact *Dijkstra* almost never worked on a machine himself, all was written on paper.

Comment: Related question: [Prolog: Compare 2 Lists and find out if at least one member of the first list exists in the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20532582/1243762)

Comment: Is the idea feasible? Are you asking if using member/2 two is feasible, or if the entire problem is feasible? It might work with member/2 but I personally would not start off with that.

Comment: To give an additional hint: you can scan both lists at the same time to check if the current element is the same in both lists. If so, consider the next element of both lists; if not, consider the same element of the subgroup list and the next element of the group list.

Comment: this is *eerily* similar to [this recent Haskell question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54129886/849891). Practically the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem suggested, an inductive solution:

```
subGroups([], []).

subGroups([X|Xs], [X|Ys]):-
    subGroups(Xs, Ys).

subGroups(Xs, [_|Ys]):-
    subGroups(Xs, Ys).

subGroupsN(Options, N, Solution) :-
    length(Solution, N),
    subGroups(Solution, Options).
```

Comment: the naming is pretty confusing though. a better name might be `subGroupsOf`. and, `subGroupsNOf` with the swapped order of arguments. a tradition (?) in Prolog is to name predicates such that `p(A,B)` is read as "A (is) p B". for instance, `father` is unclear, but `fatherOf` is.

Answer (score 2):

Really, try to write an inductive relation. Meanwhile, library(yall) coupled with library(apply) can make one liner:

```
isSubgroup(S,G,N) :- length(S,N),
    foldl({G}/[E,P,X]>>(nth1(X,G,E),X>=P),S,1,_F).
```

Comment: @GuyCoder: well, just waiting until someone eventually just posts it, and then submitting that is not really a good idea either. But CapelliC here manages to answer the question with an answer that can not be submitted, or at least not without questions that arise.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I always appreciate how he is able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

We can define this predictate by an inductive definition. A `Subgroup` is a subgroup of `Group` if:

1. the `Subgroup` is an empty list;
2. the first element of the `Subgroup` is the same as the first element of `Group`, and the rest of the `Subgroup` is a subgroup of the rest of the `Group`;
3. the `Subgroup` is a subgroup of the rest of the `Group`.

We need to update `N` accordingly such that, if the `Subgroup` is empty, then the length is `0`:

```
isSubgroup([], _, 0).              %% (1)
isSubgroup([H|TS], [H|TG], N) :-   %% (2)
    N1 is N-1,
    isSubgroup(TS, TG, N1).
isSubgroup(S, [_|TG], N) :-        %% (3)
    isSubgroup(S, TG, N).
```

The above however results in duplicate trues for the *same* subgroup. This is due to the fact that we can satisfy the predicate in multiple ways. For example if we call:

```
isSubgroup([], [1,2], 0).
```

then it is satisfied through the fact (1), but the last clause (3) also calls this with `isSubgroup([], [1], 0).`, that will then get satisfied through the fact (1), etc.

We can avoid this by making the last clause more restrictive:

```
isSubgroup([], _, 0).              %% (1)
isSubgroup([H|TS], [H|TG], N) :-   %% (2)
    N1 is N-1,
    isSubgroup(TS, TG, N1).
isSubgroup([HS|TS], [_|TG], N) :-  %% (3)
    isSubgroup([HS|TS], TG, N).
```

The above works for the given "directions" (all arguments should be grounded, are "input"). But typically one wants to use a predicate in other directions as well. We can implement a version that works basically when we use arguments as "output" as well, and still make use of *tail-call optimization (TCO)*:

```
isSubgroup(S, G, N) :-
    isSubgroup(S, G, 0, N).

isSubgroup([], _, L, L).              %% (1)
isSubgroup([H|TS], [H|TG], L, N) :-   %% (2)
    L1 is L+1,
    isSubgroup(TS, TG, L1, N).
isSubgroup([HS|TS], [_|TG], L, N) :-  %% (3)
    isSubgroup([HS|TS], TG, L, N).
```

For example:

```
?- isSubgroup([1,4,2], G, N).
G = [1, 4, 2|_2974],
N = 3 ;
G = [1, 4, _2972, 2|_2986],
N = 3 ;
G = [1, 4, _2972, _2984, 2|_2998],
N = 3 ;
G = [1, 4, _2972, _2984, _2996, 2|_3010],
N = 3 .
```

Here Prolog is thus able to propose groups for which `[1,4,2]` is a subgroup, and it is capable to determining the length `N` of the subgroup.

We can query in the opposite direction as well:

```
?- isSubgroup(S, [1,4,2], N).
S = [],
N = 0 ;
S = [1],
N = 1 ;
S = [1, 4],
N = 2 ;
S = [1, 4, 2],
N = 3 ;
S = [1, 2],
N = 2 ;
S = [4],
N = 1 ;
S = [4, 2],
N = 2 ;
S = [2],
N = 1 ;
false.
```

Prolog can, for a given group `[1,4,2]` enumerate exhaustively all possible subgroups, together with `N` the length of that subgroup.